Optimize PostgreSQL query to insert users into the database

The use case goes like this.
There is a signup endpoint on which the user will submit their email and password
4 rows have to be created at once with a couple of ids generated
The tables look like this

authentication_types



id
name




uuid
varchar


primary key



0aa4d9a9-e024-4792-bc41-36a4f3528d36
password



accounts



id
email
password
...few other columns
authentication_type_id




uuid
varchar
varchar

uuid


primary key
unique


foreign key to authentication_types


7a9d912a-69ab-4615-9058-e1bb1c4e36c5
password
...
...
0aa4d9a9-e024-4792-bc41-36a4f3528d36



users



id
enabled




uuid
boolean


primary key



fc9ca826-63dc-43b8-97b6-2e949ffd8a30
true



user_accounts



id
account_id
user_id




uuid
uuid
uuid


primary key
foreign key to accounts
foreign key to users


bd4b338f-1b5a-4b24-9908-e5cfb4080dd4
7a9d912a-69ab-4615-9058-e1bb1c4e36c5
fc9ca826-63dc-43b8-97b6-2e949ffd8a30



verification_tokens



id
expires
token
account_id




uuid
timestamptz
varchar
uuid


primary key

unique
foreign key to accounts


865a6389-67ea-4e38-a48f-9f4b60ffe816
...
...
7a9d912a-69ab-4615-9058-e1bb1c4e36c5



When a new signup happens I want to do the following things

Generate a uuid and insert a row into accounts
Generate a uuid and insert a row into users
Generate a uuid + Take the id of the inserted row from accounts and users and insert into user_accounts
Generate a uuid + token + account id generated above and insert into verification_tokens

This is the query I came up with after a lot of thought. Get the authentication type id for say password and run a CTE with some uuid generation in every step. Is there a way to optimize this any further?
WITH account_data(id, email, password, authentication_type_id) AS (
      VALUES( gen_random_uuid()
             ,:email
             ,:password
             ,(SELECT id 
               FROM authentication_types 
               WHERE name = :authenticationTypeName) ) )
,ins1(user_id) AS (
      INSERT INTO users(id, enabled) 
      VALUES( gen_random_uuid()
             ,true)
      RETURNING id AS user_id )
,ins2(account_id) AS (
      INSERT INTO accounts (id, email, password, authentication_type_id) 
      SELECT id
            ,email
            ,password
            ,authentication_type_id 
      FROM account_data 
      RETURNING id AS account_id )
,ins3 AS (
      INSERT INTO user_accounts (id, account_id, user_id) 
      VALUES( gen_random_uuid()
             ,(SELECT account_id 
               FROM ins2)
             ,(SELECT user_id 
               FROM ins1)       ) )
INSERT INTO verification_tokens (id, token, account_id) 
VALUES( gen_random_uuid()
       ,:token
       ,(SELECT account_id 
         FROM   ins2)     ) 
RETURNING (SELECT account_id FROM ins2) AS id

If there is a faster method to execute the above query, I would be glad to hear. Thank you for your help in advance
EDIT 1
Here is a sample query with actual data
WITH account_data(id, email, password, authentication_type_id) AS (
      VALUES( gen_random_uuid()
             ,'abc@example.com'
             ,'$2a$12$71qwp8jK0z6EVbpe9FZSIeHQkYh4Wtn2sOxH/Y3xuEhSLP1IjPAEK'
             ,(SELECT id 
               FROM authentication_types 
               WHERE name = 'password') ) )
,ins1(user_id) AS (
      INSERT INTO users(id, enabled) 
      VALUES( gen_random_uuid()
             ,true)
      RETURNING id AS user_id )
,ins2(account_id) AS (
      INSERT INTO accounts (id, email, password, authentication_type_id) 
      SELECT id
            ,email
            ,password
            ,authentication_type_id 
      FROM account_data 
      RETURNING id AS account_id )
,ins3 AS (
      INSERT INTO user_accounts (id, account_id, user_id) 
      VALUES( gen_random_uuid()
             ,(SELECT account_id 
               FROM ins2)
             ,(SELECT user_id 
               FROM ins1)       ) )
INSERT INTO verification_tokens (id, token, account_id) 
VALUES( gen_random_uuid()
       ,'$2a$12$VNP/ya5ILSP.yYjSa3anyuZhm8Jxc97Y3p95grDjS/Xe1XjBmX/VK'
       ,(SELECT account_id 
         FROM   ins2)     ) 
RETURNING (SELECT account_id FROM ins2) AS id

Here is the visual query analyzer

Here is the explain analyze result


Why are you looking for a faster method? You could try to pre-generate blank profiles and when a new user registers, you'd run a single update accounts to fill out the email+password and return the account_id. A trigger can monitor how many blanks are left and when you run low, generate a new batch when the traffic is low. Still, unless the server is barely running under some really heavy load, and/or tables are massive and IO slow, this query should be imperceptibly quick. All it does is roll some dice, verify some constraints on write, then write a tiny amount of data

Maybe you have some expensive triggers set up that get cascaded by the this statement, or a ton of unused indexes? How big is authentication_types and do you have an index on its name column? Can you attach the output of explain (analyze,buffers,verbose) for this query, as well as the index definitions?

Is this too slow?

@Zegarek i updated the question to include the output of explain analyze. The only reason I wanted to investigate is because the express app on my end does a login before each test using the query above as part of integration tests. Takes about 40 seconds for 350 tests currently. Hence I was concerned if the login query could be sped up slightly

I'll take it as a given that:

your design is constrained to DML-based CRUD.
the uniqueness check for whether an email already exists in accounts is being done on the back-end prior to this operation or that unique constraint violations raised by ins2 are appropriately trapped and handled by the API service based on the SQLSTATE of the response - the below optimizations rely on this advance knowledge that the constraints will all pass

A couple of small tweaks to the DML:
WITH account_data(id, email, password, authentication_type_id) AS (
      VALUES( gen_random_uuid()
             ,:email
             ,:password
             ,:authentication_type_id  --cache these at the level of the CRUD service and submit parameterized 
             ) 
), ins1(user_id) AS (
      INSERT INTO users(id, enabled) 
      VALUES( gen_random_uuid(), true )
      RETURNING id AS user_id 
), ins2(account_id) AS (
      INSERT INTO accounts (id, email, password, authentication_type_id) 
      SELECT id
            ,email
            ,password
            ,:authentication_type_id  --parameterized
      FROM account_data
      RETURNING id AS account_id
), ins3 AS (
      INSERT INTO user_accounts (id, account_id, user_id) 
      SELECT gen_random_uuid()
             , account_id
             , user_id )
      FROM ins1, ins2  --ditch the subqueries, just use the cartesian product of the two preceding always-single records
)
INSERT INTO verification_tokens (id, token, account_id) 
SELECT gen_random_uuid()
       , :token
       , account_id 
FROM ins2
RETURNING account_id AS id;

You can additionally try altering the DDL to make the PRIMARY KEY and FOREIGN KEY constraints DEFERRABLE/INITIALLY DEFERRED, which will cause the constraint checks and index updates to only run together upon the successful completion of all 4 INSERTs rather than after each one.  This should reduce your overhead and deadlock risk in a high-concurrency live environment.
Note that you might not see any material improvement in benchmark performance until you get a prod-like concurrency load on the database.

Although it does look better, you can expect zero impact from the syntactic cleanup. Deferring constraints on a single statement producing a single row in 4 tables will also remain neutral to how this performs - in autocommit your query will return when your client gets confirmation it committed successfully, which means it has to wait for the constraint validation anyway.

Without autocommit, you can overdo it: if the app proceeds with the account_id this creates and let the commit (and thus deferred constraint validation) happen asynchronously, you introduce a window of time when your worker manages an id that's not yet known to anything else on the db, or to any other worker. Your app decouples from the db, running around with a rejected or not-yet-existing account. Still, if you do it right, you could shave off some wait time, and fast-forward a few steps in the app - just make sure to check back with the db before you do anything more with the account.
